# How to differentiate between php constant and string

Tags: php, pdo, constants

I am storing db credentials in a file as constant and including in another file. I am using PDO to connecting with database. But It's unable to differentiating between string and constant variables. So how to differentiate it to connect with database?
This is my code line-

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:hostname='DB_HOST'; dbname='P_DB'", "'DB_USER'", "'DB_PASSKEY'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP constants cannot be instantiated within a string; you need to concatenate them to the string, or, in the case of your user and password fields, just reference the constant:

```php
$db = new PDO("mysql:hostname=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . P_DB, DB_USER, DB_PASSKEY);
```

Comment: You are right. Thank You. But there should be something which help to differentiate.

Comment: @MdFarzan this is why PHP8 will now flag an error if you use something like `DB_USER` without quotes but without defining it as a constant first.